# Get the executed jpa query in spring aspect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

*Environment* 
Spring boot version :- 2.0.1.RELEASE
AspectJ version :- 1.8.9
Hibernate version :- 5.2.14.Final

I have the below spring interceptor:-

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class JpaInterceptor {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JpaInterceptor.class);

    private ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> sdf = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:SSS]");
        }
    };

    @Pointcut("execution(public !void org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.*(..))")
    public void jpaHandler() {
    }

    @Around("jpaHandler()")
    public Object logMethodCall(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
        logger.info(sdf.get().format(new Date()) + methodName);
        return jp.proceed();
    }

}
```

I don't have any criteria or native sql query in `@Repository` for a moment.
I want to get the query to be executed by JPA in JpaInterceptor in `@Around` advice. 
I know that we can enable `spring.jpa.show-sql = true` to see the queries but my requirement is to get the jpa query in spring aspect.
Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: No you cannot... The query is generated a lot later and not by Spring Data JPA (that is merely a wrapper for your JPA provider). The query is generated by Hibernate before it executes the query. Why do you need the query?

Comment: I am evaluating that if can add/edit the column in a query for my use case and can execute the edited query through EntityManager.

Comment: I would strongly suggest not to do that as that will lead to much more issues. The column names (or aliases) have been chosen by the JPA engine and if you start messing around with those it won't be able to map the query results.